# How would I used sklearn.train_test_split to train on two targets (X_S and X_S2 in code)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, train-test-split

In my code, I want to split my classification data set into a training and testing dataset where the targets are two variables of X_S and X_S2. How would I extend my code (where I only considered X_S as a target) to include both targets of X_S and X_S2?

```
def split(X_BG, X_S, test_sample_size):

  np.random.shuffle(X_BG)

  #Label data
  y_S = np.ones(len(X_S))
  y_BG = np.zeros(len(X_BG)) 

  X = np.append(X_S, X_BG, axis=0)
  y = np.append(y_S, y_BG, axis=0)

  # CNN architecture is built to take color images. 
  # Therefore, input shape is: 1 colour channel + 1 imagege channel (flattened)
  X = X.reshape( (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2], 1) )

  # Split data into training and testing samples
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_sample_size, shuffle=do_shuffle)
  # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=do_shuffle)


  # Reshape target vectors
  y = to_categorical(y, 2)
  y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 2)
  y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 2)

  input_shape = X[0].shape

  return X, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, input_shape

X_2500, X_train_2500, X_test_2500, y_train_2500, y_test_2500, input_shape_2500 = split(X_BG_2500, X_S_2500, 0.25)
X_1500, X_train_1500, X_test_1500, y_train_1500, y_test_1500, input_shape_1500 = split(X_BG_1500, X_S_1500, 0.25)
X_600, X_train_600, X_test_600, y_train_600, y_test_600, input_shape_600 = split(X_BG_600, X_S_600, 0.25)
X_300, X_train_300, X_test_300, y_train_300, y_test_300, input_shape_300 = split(X_BG_300, X_S_300, 0.25)

print("Input vector shape:", input_shape_2500)
print("Number of input samples:", len(X_2500))
```

I tried including extending the array for X and Y in the beginning to include X_S2 as shown below

```
def split(X_BG, X_S, X_S2):

  #Label data
  y_S = np.ones(len(X_S))
  y_S2 = np.ones(len(X_S2))
  y_BG = np.zeros(len(X_BG)) 

  X = np.append(X_S, X_S2, X_BG, axis=0)
  y = np.append(y_S, y_S2, y_BG, axis=0)

  # CNN architecture is built to take color images. 
  # Therefore, input shape is: 1 colour channel + 1 imagege channel (flattened)
  X = X.reshape( (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2], 1) )

  # Split data into training and testing samples
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_sample_size)
  # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=do_shuffle)


  # Reshape target vectors
  y = to_categorical(y, 2)
  y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 2)
  y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 2)

  input_shape = X[0].shape

  return X, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, input_shape

X_2500, X_train_2500, X_test_2500, y_train_2500, y_test_2500, input_shape_2500 = split(X_BG_2500, X_S_2500, X_S2_2500)
X_1500, X_train_1500, X_test_1500, y_train_1500, y_test_1500, input_shape_1500 = split(X_BG_1500, X_S_1500, X_S2_1500)
X_600, X_train_600, X_test_600, y_train_600, y_test_600, input_shape_600 = split(X_BG_600, X_S_600, X_S2_600)
X_300, X_train_300, X_test_300, y_train_300, y_test_300, input_shape_300 = split(X_BG_300, X_S_300, X_S2_300)

print("Input vector shape:", input_shape_2500)
print("Number of input samples:", len(X_2500))
```

but I keep getting the error of _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by two targets? Like you want an individual training snd testing set for each target? Could you please show what your expected output is?

Comment: I want to identify signals of X_S and X_S2 in a dataset with background noise of X_BG. SO far, to get a splitting data set for my two targets X_S and X_S2, I would have to do the splitting twice. Is there a way I can compile X_S with X_S2 to create one training and testing set for the signals (X_S, X_S2)  and the background (X_BG)?

Comment: Please provide a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *both* minimal *and* reproducible), with sample input, desired result, and a clear explanation of where you are stuck. If you specifically need help resolving that error, please also include the full error traceback message. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to split your data to train,validation,test over 2 targets (labels) for a classification task.
In other words- you want to know how to split in multi-label in a stratified way.

If so, there are several methods, all that I know of are iterative.
There is an implementation for one of them:
http://scikit.ml/stratification.html

```
from skmultilearn.model_selection import IterativeStratification
test_fraction = 0.8

stratifier = IterativeStratification(n_splits=3, order=2, sample_distribution_per_fold=[test_fraction, 1.0-test_fraction])
train_indices, test_indices = next(stratifier.split(features, chosen_targets))
```

If I didn't understand properly, please add more details.